# Filter by CharField pretending it is DateField in Django ORM/mySql

Tags: python, mysql, django, orm

I am working with a already-done mySQL Database using Django ORM and I need to filter rows by date - if it wasn't that dates are not in Date type but normal Varchar(20) stored as *dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm(:ss)*.
With a free query I would transform the field into date and I would use > and < operators to filter the results but before doing this I was wondering whether Django ORM provides a more elegant way to do so without writing raw SQL queries.

I look forward to any suggestion.

**EDIT:** my raw query would look like

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE STR_TO_DATE(mydate,'%d/%m/%Y %H:%i') > STR_TO_DATE('30/12/2020 00:00', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i')
```

Thank you.

Comment: Isn't creating a `DateTimeField` and performing a data migration to fill in the date an option: after that migration, the `varchar` column can be removed, and then you thus can easily use the `DateTimeField` column to filter properly.

Comment: Can you furthermore share the raw query, likely one can make an ORM equivalent for that.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem your suggestion is not realizable unfortunately due the fact I cannot write/alterate the db, only reading and getting data I need. Anyway I edited the first post with the raw query I would use to get my result. I know it's a dirty way of working but that field must remain only a text field...

Comment: it is not only a dirty way, but also an *inefficient* one since a database can add an index on the datetime column, and thus makes filtering efficient, whereas converting it to a date will result in a scan over all the data. If the number of records grows significantly, it will render the database unresponsive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will assume your model looks like this:

```py
from django.db import models

class Event(models.Model):
    mydate = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Event at {self.mydate}'
```

You can construct a [Django query expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/expressions/) to represent this computation. This expression consists of:

- `Func` objects representing your `STR_TO_DATE` function calls.
- An `F` object representing your field name.
- A `GreaterThan` function to represent your `>` comparison.

```py
from django.db.models import F, Func, Value
from django.db.models.lookups import GreaterThan
from .models import Event

# Create some events for this example
Event(mydate="29/12/2020 00:00").save()
Event(mydate="30/12/2020 00:00").save()
Event(mydate="31/12/2020 00:00").save()

class STR_TO_DATE(Func):
    "Lets us use the STR_TO_DATE() function from SQLite directly in Python"
    function = 'STR_TO_DATE'

# This Django query expression converts the mydate field
# from a string into a date, using the STR_TO_DATE function.
mydate = STR_TO_DATE(F('mydate'), Value('%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'))

# This Django query expression represents the value 30/12/2020
# as a date.
date_30_12_2020 = STR_TO_DATE(Value('30/12/2020 00:00'), Value('%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'))

# This Django query expression puts the other two together,
# creating a query like this: mydate < 30/12/2020
expr = GreaterThan(mydate, date_30_12_2020)

# Use the expression as a filter
events = Event.objects.filter(expr)
print(events)

# You can also use the annotate function to add a calculated
# column to your query...
events_with_date = Event.objects.annotate(date=mydate)

# Then, you just treat your calculated column like any other
# field in your database. This example uses a range filter
# (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#range)
events = events_with_date.filter(date__range=["2020-12-30", "2020-12-31"])
print(events)
```

I tested this answer with Django 4.0.1 and MySQL 8.0.

Comment: Thank you first - for your prompt reply, and I do sorry for my late one... IT has a logic I didn't fully get. What if I'd like to use the lookup _mydate__range=[date_1, date_2]_? Would it be possible?

Comment: Yes, it would be possible; I added it to the example above.

Comment: Excellent. It does work! Thank you very much @Jeff Booth!

Comment: Brilliant technique for when you're stuck with a badly designed database, thanks. For anyone needing to do this with postgres, the equivalent function is just `TO_DATE`.

Comment: The postgres version also has a different formatting syntax, documented here:
https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-date-functions/postgresql-to_date/